# How does interpreting a script work?

Tags: programming-languages, compilers, interpreters

Suppose I have a script (`.vbs`, for example) that is stored in a file. How does the code in the file get converted into machine instructions?  What is between the vbs file and the processor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Scripting" languages are typically *interpreted*, not compiled.  That means that there will be a program called the "interpreter" for that language, which reads the programs written in the language, and executes them. You can start reading about interpreters from the Wikepedia entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)

A compiler, on the other hand, *translates* a program in the programming language into machine language, and lets the CPU execute the machine language program.  The only reason for compiling instead of interpreting is for *speed*.  The CPU can typically execute the translated machine language program about 10-100 times faster than any interpreter.  The reason is that the CPU is implemented in hardware.  Otherwise, there is nothing that a CPU can do that a program can't.

Interpreted programs runs slow as compared to compiled ones due to the difference in execution process.

Scripting languages are usually used for expressing high-level operations.  For such things, the speed advantage of the CPU becomes much less significant.  So, interpreting them can be competitive to compiling them.

Comment: These days some scripting languages are compiled on-the-fly to bytecodes of an internal VM.

Comment: There are very few, if any, "pure" interpreters, in the sense that they execute the text file provided by the programmer directly. Even 8-bit interpreted BASIC tokenised keywords first.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on a lot of factors. If it is a pure interpreter (like most shells), the interpreter reads each line/instruction, analyzes it, and executes it. If it is a pure compiler, the program (or a part of it) is read in, analyzed, and then the machine language is written out to run later. Many programming languages are implemented by compiling into a fake machine language (like Java's Virtual Machine; Python and Perl does so too, but not so overtly), and the fake machine language is then interpreted.

This is a *vast* area, to get an idea of how a real compiler works a good introduction is Fraser and Hanson's "A Retargetable C Compiler: Design and Implementation", the [full code](https://sites.google.com/site/lccretargetablecompiler/) of the compiler is available.

Comment: Thank you Von. Does the interpreter for a *.vbs file come with the the windows OS? Because if I create a *.vbs file on my machine and double click it, it works. And I did not install any interpretor.

Comment: @developer747: Yes, a VB Script interpreter comes with Windows.